# Do I need to get app permissions approved before building my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having an issue where I'm wanting to build a web app - but until I can have it built to show Facebook, they won't give my app permissions (specifically manage_pages and read_page_mailboxes).

So, obviously my code for this doesn't work at the moment.

Is there a sandbox mode where I can write and test all my code, then send it into Facebook submissions for full approval once it actually works?

Comment: Yes, there is a sandbox mode. You can use the full extend of permissions either with your admin user of the app, or with the created test users without having it approved yet by Facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a developer, you can use permissions that have not been approved to build your application. You can also create test users from the App Settings page to create users to test your application - all can use unapproved permissions.

Once your application is built, you can then submit it to Facebook to get the permissions approved for end-users. Just make sure you are using the Developer account or a Test user account to test your code during development.

You'll see a notice if you're using a permission that isn't approved.